# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode() in Xampp

Tags: php, json

I'm using Xampp to run a php file using Brackets. I got this error:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode() in Xampp

I don't know if this is related but I checked the php info file and there are no disabled files. In the json section it says support    enabled, json version   1.4.0. In the ini file I searched for json but couldn't find anything.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What is the PHP version? Do you have `json` in the output of `phpinfo();`? How about `php -m` command output?

Comment: Do you mean Adobe Brackets?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Hi Ruslan, I'm running PHP Version 7.0.9. In the phpinfo(); I can find a section where it says json I'm not sure what you mean by output.. also I can't find php -m written anywhere in the file..

Comment: @OlafDietsche yes.. this one: http://brackets.io/

Comment: Maybe Brackets comes with its own PHP without JSON support.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Ubuntu use the following command in command line shell

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

if you are on windows, edit php.ini and enable the json extension.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.. I'm not sure what Ubuntu is

Comment: go to xampp/php and look for php.ini edit this file and search the json extension, remove the ";" (semi-colon) sign from the start of the json extension line. save the file, restart the xampp.

Comment: I searched but I cant find json written anywhere in the php.ini file